# Uniform convergence on a subset

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am fairly new on the concept of uniform convergence and I have the following basic question.

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions defined on a set $A \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n = f$ uniformly on $A$. Is it true that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on any subset of $A$? If not, can someone provide a counterexample?

Comment: If you just write down the definition of uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $A$, you should see the answer immediately.

Comment: @MPW Ok, so the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $A$ to $f$ if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbf{N}$ such that for all $x \in A$ and for all $n \ge N$, it follows that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. So if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $A$, then it must converge uniformly on any $B \subseteq A$ since if $x \in B$ then $x \in A$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: A more synthetic way to write the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ is $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_A \to 0$, where $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_A=\sup_{x\in A} \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert$. Then you can see that $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_B \leq \lVert f_n-f\rVert_A$ as soon as $B \subset A$, so your claim follows.

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$